# List<string> differ from cs to blazor page

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a dictionary of string and object, and I am filling it with same values in cs class and in a blazor page:

Blazor page and Cs class:

```
ExportOptions exportOptions = new();
exportOptions.Options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
exportOptions.Options.Add("SheetNames", new List<string> { "Sheet1" });
```

When I am deserializing the value of the dictionary, I am getting the following error only when using the Cs class:

ERROR:
**System.Text.Json.JsonException: ''S' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.'**

Code used for deserializing:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(exportOptions.Options.GetValueOrDefault("SheetNames").ToString());
```

When debugging, the only difference is the following:

Blazor debug:

[image]

Cs debug:

[image]

Comment: If I'm correct, `exportOptions.Options.GetValueOrDefault("SheetNames").ToString()` wont work because you're essentially doing `List<string>.ToString()` which wont be JSON string. Unless you're overriding `ToString()` and haven't posted it in your question?

Comment: But how is it working in a way while it's not in the other way, although both are filling the dictionary in the same way? And no, I didn't override the ToString() method

Comment: Show the Json you are trying to de-serialize in your question

Answer (score 0):

- Supposing that `exportOptions.Options` is of type `Dictionary<string, object>` as shown in the OP.
- Supposing that `GetValueOrDefault` is (equivalent to) [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-6.0).
- Supposing that the value returned by `GetValueOrDefault` is of type `List<string>` (Again OP code and obscure images).

One can [evaluate](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g5QDwY) `exportOptions.Options.GetValueOrDefault("SheetNames").ToString()` to be **"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"**
This string is not a valid JSON, and start by a **S**. Hence the message **'S' is an invalid start of a value. [first line, first char]**.

The real question is : why one want to deserialize **an object**?
You deserialize a **string** to build an **object**.

Comment: I need to use Json.Deserialize because the type of the dictionary value is `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`

Comment: @Hanady in the Blazor part maybe. But in the C# part it looks like it's not the case.